# What is the magic of async move {}?

Tags: rust, async-await, future, rust-tokio

I am working with tokio and I spent whole day trying to create a vector of futures.

I always got into a fight with borrow checker until finally someone suggested to use `async move {}` trick.

I am failing to comprehend why this one works (unlike the naive approach).

Can somebody help me understand that please?

```
use futures::future;

async fn kill(processes: Vec<tokio::process::Child>) {
    let mut deaths = Vec::new();

    for mut p in processes {
        // following works
        deaths.push(async move { p.kill().await });

        // naive approach would trigger error:
        // deaths.push(p.kill());
        // "borrowed value does not live long enough"
    }
    
    future::join_all(deaths).await;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each time you write `async { ... }` the Rust compiler generates code for a state machine, which we call a task. In your example, the tasks are collected into a vector, but are only actually executed after the loop is finished.

Simplifying considerably, the task that Rust generates looks something like this:

```
struct Task1<'a> {
    p: &'a tokio::process::Child,
}

impl Future for Task1 { ... }
```

Without the `move` keyword, these tasks hold *references* to `p`. `p` only lives for one iteration of the loop, but the task is run after the loop, so this reference is invalid - if Rust allowed you to use it, it would be a dangling pointer, triggering Undefined Behaviour.

Writing `move async` means that the generated task has taken ownership of `p`. It's not a reference anymore, the value is part of the task:

```
struct Task1 {
    p: tokio::process::Child,
}

impl Future for Task1 { ... }
```

Comment: Ok, so to understand it, p is a mut reference to element in vector, right? And we can have only a single mut reference, so that is the reason it has to be moved?

Comment: Wrong, `p` inside of `move {}` is a 'field' of the implicit structure generated for the block.

Comment: I am confused. So, what happens if I write deaths.push(p.kill()) ? Why doesn't it work?

Comment: Because `p` gets dropped at the `}` of the loop, so you can't hold on to a reference to it in `deaths` which is still valid until `}` of the function. It would work if `kill` consumed it's parameter instead of taking `&mut self`